# I can't access data from controller to view(tpl = template) OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

Can't access variable data from controller to view(template tpl file)
I have very basic function

```
public function index() {
$message = "hello";
return $this->load->view('common/hello.tpl', $message );
} 


In view template i try to get $message variable but not defined

<?php echo $message; ?>

public function index() {
$message = "hello";
return $this->load->view('common/hello.tpl', $message );
}
```

In view template hello.tpl i try to get $message variable but not defined

This is only example. I have model which must load but for now I need only to access from Controller to View.... Help..

Answer (score 0):

In your given code, the template has no chance to know anything about a variable called `$message` as you only transmit the **value** of that variable. According to [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru/13484904#13484904), you should add that variable an array like `$data` like this:

```
$data['message'] = $message;
```

This makes the content of `$message` available under the same name in your template. If you change the key (eg. to `$data['otherKey']`), it will get available under `$otherKey`

Afterwards, transmit that value array to the `view` method:

```
return $this->load->view('common/hello.tpl', $data );
```

Comment: Okej I try with this in controller


 $this->data['message'] = $message;

  return $this->load->view('common/reifenmontage.tpl', $data);
 }


and this in view tpl 
<?php echo $message; ?>

Not work
I try to set also 
return $this->load->view('common/reifenmontage.tpl', $message);
also not work
reason?
always not defined variable

Comment: @AlexAl I've edited my answer once more after having looked up the current conventions. That thread is a bit old...

Comment: I try this but already not work 

$data['message'] = $message;


 return $this->load->view('common/reifenmontage.tpl', $data );

in view 
  <?php  echo $message; ?>

Again not underfined variable

Comment: Okey this reifenmontage.tpl is my real file name , i write hello.tpl only  to explain you. I have good knowledge in MCV I work Laravel but this opencart is very confused for me. hello.tpl is for ease to understand.... What is problem?

Comment: If I knew what is going wrong here, I'd love to help you out. But currently, I'm out of ideas - sorry

Comment: My hello/reifenmontage.tpl is on popup? Maybe that problem?

Answer (score 0):

First You need  post what version of OC are using... So if you use OC version 1.x  in controller file you should define your data like this:
`$this->data['message'] = 'hello';`
 and render tpl:

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/hello.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/hello.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/payment/hello.tpl';
        }   

        $this->render();
```

if you use version 2 or higher you should define:
`$data['message'] = 'hello';`
and render in tpl lik:

```
return $this->load->view('extension/payment/hello', $data);
```

In tpl retrieve data:
`<?php echo $message: ?>` 
if OC version 3.x.x where is used twig templates... 
retrieve  data `{{ message }}`.

This is very simple if you just take a look how it works in OC corresponding version.

So for  OC2.3 as you have defined, should be:
controller hello.php file:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHello extends Controller {
    public function index() {

    $data['hello'] = 'Hello!!!';

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/hello', $data));
    }
}
```

`hello.tpl` file something like this:

```
?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">

 <?php echo $hello; ?>


</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: Okey I try this but without succes. Look my code 

Controller

class ControllerCommonMotorTypeCustom extends Controller {
 public function index() { 
   $data['message'] = 'TEST';
   return $this->load->view('common/motor_type_custom', $data);
}
}


and my view tpl file 

<div>
<h1> DSA </h1> 
 <?php var_dump($message); ?>
 </div>

underfined variable 

All work except variable $message....??? 
Where is mistake?
Mistake is not in name of file ...I don't know where is?

Comment: Maybe i must registrater this route anywhere?

Comment: which version of OC?

Comment: // Version
define('VERSION', '2.3.0.2');

Comment: What is problem? Maybe url don't read my function? 
I really don't know reason. I am new in open cart

Comment: I have edited my first answer little bit. I hope it's should help to understand.

Comment: Undefined all variable. This in my structure probably...My  call(include) my template in Javascript popup....maybe that problem...